# Encontrar la palabra más larga de un Array con Javascript

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Quiero encontrar la palabra mas larga de strings de mi array con esta function de javascript, pero no se que anda mal que sigo sin encontrar la solucion, aca les dejo mi codigo.

```
function stringMasLarga(strings) {

let largo=strings[0];
let la_palabra_mas_larga='';

> recorro el arreglo

for (let i = 0; i<strings.length; i++){

> uso una condicion 

  if (strings[i].length>largo.length) {
    la_palabra_mas_larga=strings[i];
  }
}

> retorno la palabra mas larga por ultimo

return la_palabra_mas_larga;
}
```

Comment: ¿`var largo=strings[0];` debería ser `var largo=strings[0].length;`? De todos modos tu función no devuelve la cadena más larga sino la longitud de la cadena más larga.

Comment: y que falta, para que devuelva el string  mas largo?

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask]. Has realizado una edición a tu pregunta en la cual el cambio sobre el código implica que el mismo funciona correctamente. Si alguna de las respuestas o comentarios te ha sido de utilidad puedes marcarlo como útil haciendo clic en el icono de `upvote`. En el caso de una respuesta válida puedes hacer clic en el `checkmark` para aceptarla. También he revertido tu edición para que la pregunta sea coherente con las respuestas. Saludos

Comment: hola como lo resolviste? tengo el mismo problema y necesito la palabra más larga de unas frases (strings) que pertenecen a un array.

Answer (score 5):

No termine de entender del todo tu función así que decidí hacerte un ejemplo.

- Tendremos el vector con los strings y un vector vacio
- Iteramos el vector actual y llenamos al vector vacio con los valores numéricos
  de la longitud de cada string recuperado
- En una variable obtenemos [el valor numérico mas grande](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max) de los elementos del vector
  recién llenado
- En un segundo ciclo for iteramos nuevamente el vector de palabras
- Con un condicional interno evaluamos la lontitud de cada uno de los elementos
  contra la longitud máxima que recuperamos en el paso 3
- Si esa condición se cumple entonces imprimimos a elemento que es la variable que
  nos ayuda a recuperar cada uno de los elementos del vector original

Código

```js
    let palabras = ['mucho', 'muchomucho', 'muchomuchomucho', 'muchomuchomuchomuchoa'];
    let totales  = [];
    for(let palabra of palabras) {
      totales.push(palabra.length);
    }
    
    let maximo = Math.max.apply(null, totales);
    
    for (let elemento of palabras) {
      if (elemento.length === maximo) {
        console.log(elemento);
      }
    }
```

Como menciona en el enlace si la función `apply()` recibe `NULL` como primer argumento entonces el objeto global sería el usado (*que para estos casos sería `window`*)

**Referencia**

- [Ciclo for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of)

Comment: que significa el "of " ?

Comment: que significa el null?

Comment: no se puede hacer usando el ciclo for que use en mi codigo?

Comment: @BetaM, ya lo lei y no me explica porque el null.  no lo entendi bien

Answer (score 4):

Lo tienes casi. Creo que te (y nos) sería más fácil razonar sobre el programa si usas nombres mejores para tus variables. Usar nombres demasiado largos hace el código más difícil de seguir. Por otra parte, ¿hay que obtener la palabra más larga o la cadena más larga (son cosas distintas)? ¿Y `largo` es una longitud o una cadena? La confusión te ha llevado a usar dos variables donde sólo necesitas una.

*(Por cierto, ¿vas a nombrar tus variables en español o en inglés?)*

```
function cadenaMasLarga(cadenas) {
   ...
}
```

Vamos a implementar tu solución que es la más directa: ir cadena por cadena, guardando en cada paso la nueva cadena si es más larga que las que hemos encontrado hasta entonces. La primera candidata es la primera cadena:

```
function cadenaMasLarga(cadenas) {

   let candidata = cadenas[0];

   [...]

}
```

El bucle lo podemos empezar en la segunda cadena, porque no necesitamos comparar la primera cadena consigo misma. Una vez terminado el bucle, lo que haya en la variable `candidata` es la cadena más larga y es lo que debe devolver la función (aunque puede haber otras cadenas con la misma longitud, pero no has especificado qué pasa en ese caso):

```
function cadenaMasLarga(cadenas) {

   let candidata = cadenas[0];

   for (let i = 1; i < cadenas.length; i++) {
       if (cadenas[i].length > candidata.length) {
           candidata = cadenas[i];
       }
   }

   return candidata;

}
```

Comment: hola, ya lo resolvi, muchas gracias por los consejos!

Comment: Gracias por apreciarlos. Te dejo aquí otro código alternativo usando programación funcional: `return cadenas.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.length > b.length ? a : b; });`

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar [`arra.reduce(callback, accumulator)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) así:

- Establecemos el acumulador (*segundo parámetro de `reduce`*) a un valor inicial vacio (`eg: ''`);
- Luego en la función reductora (*primer parámetro de `reduce`*) comparamos el largo de la palabran en el acumulador contra el largo de la palabra en el arreglo.

  - Si la palabra en el acumulador es mas larga entonces devolvemos ésta.
  - Si la palabra en el arreglo es mas larga entonces devolvemos ésta.

### Ejemplo:

```js
let palabras = ['mucho', 'muchomuchomuchomuchoa', 'muchomucho', 'muchomuchomucho'];
let palabra = palabras.reduce((acc, val) => acc.length > val.length ? acc : val, '');
console.log(palabra);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function stringMasLarga(strings) {
  var largo=strings[0];
  var cadena_larga=""; //Creamos otra variable para almacenar el String
  for (var i = 0; i<strings.length; i++) {
    if (strings[i].length>largo) {
      largo=strings[i].length;
      cadena_larga=strings[i]; //Guardamos el contenido del String mas Largo
    }
  }
  return largo;
}
```

Comment: hola, no me funciona del todo , solo me tomo el primer elemento de mi array

Answer (score 0):

Aqui presento otra solucion a este problema

```js
let palabras = ['mucho', 'muchomucho', 'muchomuchomucho', 'muchomuchomuchomuchoa'];
//Convertimos todos los datos a una estructura de nuestra conveniencia. 
let palabraMasLarga = palabras.map(x => {
  return {
    longitud: x.length,
    palabra: x
  }
   
})
//Ordenamos en base a su longitud
.sort((a, b) => a.longitud > b.longitud ? 1 : -1)
//Obtenemos el ultimo elemento que debe ser el que contiene
// la palabra con mayor longitud
.pop()
//Obtenemos la palabra
.palabra

console.log(palabraMasLarga)
```

## EDICION

Esta línea `a.longitud > b.longitud ? 1 : -1` es una abreviación de un `if else`. Esto se puede interpetrar como `condicionAEvaluar ? mostrarEstoSiEsTrue: mostrarEstoSiEsFalse`

```js
console.log(true ?'Se muestra esto': 'Se muestra esto otro de aca')
console.log(false?'Se muestra esto': 'Se muestra esto otro de aca')
```

Comment: @BetaM, corregido.

Comment: que significa el signo de pregunta cuando ordenas en base a su longitud?

Comment: @AyelenFernandez Edite para responder a tu duda.

Answer (score 0):

Llego un poco tarde, pero creo que esta podría ser una solución eficiente y corta.
Como verás aprovechamos el método [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) que nos brinda [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Se define una función como constante, la cual nos retornará la palabra más larga basado en la siguiente comparación: `longest_word.length > current_word.length`, la cual evalúa si la palabra más larga hasta este momento es más larga que la actual. Y con base en esa comparación se retorna la palabra más larga

**Nota:** Se está haciendo uso de un [if ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) para acortar las lineas de código.

```js
const getLongestWord = (words) => {
  return words.reduce((longest_word, current_word) => {
    return longest_word.length > current_word.length ? longest_word : current_word;
  });
};

console.log(getLongestWord(["Hola", "mundo"]));

console.log(getLongestWord(["Hola", "mundo", "damisela", "caballero"]));

console.log(getLongestWord(["Hola", "mundo", "damisela", "caballero", "anticonstitucionalista", "revolucionario"]));
```