# ¿Cómo devolver la palabra más larga de entre varias frases (strings) pertenecientes a un array ? JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `array` de frases y tengo que buscar la palabra más larga entre todas las frases (`stings`) del `array` y devolverla.

Ejemplo:

```
laPalabraMasLarga(['hola, un placer', 'beber mucha cerveza'])
// debe devolver 'cerveza'.
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Encontrar la palabra más larga de un Array con Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369748/encontrar-la-palabra-m%c3%a1s-larga-de-un-array-con-javascript)

Comment: no, abajo desarrollan la cadena más larga y yo necesito la palabra de las frases de la cadena.

Comment: Se debe tomar en cuenta los caracteres especiales `.`, `,`, `?` en el conteo de los caracteres? ejemplo 'hola,' o debe ser solo 'hola'? La separación entre las frases se toma con el ` ` espacio?

Comment: sólo las palabras por ejemplo

Comment: array = ["hola,que gusto estar aqui hablando contigo", ""hoy comí puré"]  debe retornar "hablando"

Comment: sin caracteres especiales

Comment: Entiendo, eso sugiero que lo agregues a la pregunta así queda mas explicita. Por otro lado, haz intentado algo?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes lograrlo de esta manera.

```js
function laPalabraMasLarga(arreglo) {

  return arreglo
    .reduce((a, b) => {
      // Ordenamos todo obteniendo un solo arreglo de todas las frases existentes
      a.push(...b.split(" "))
      return a
    }, [])
    //Quitamos los falsos positivos
    .map(x => x.replace(/,/g, ''))
    //Ordenamos de menor a mayor
    .sort((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? 1 : -1)
    //Obtenemos el mayor
    .pop()

}


console.log(laPalabraMasLarga(['hola, un placer', 'beber mucha cerveza', 'falso positivo,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,', 'supercalifragilisticoexpialidoso']))
```

Answer (score 1):

El método [`array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) recorre un arreglo y devuelve solo un elemento, generalmente se usa para sumar (incluso en el ejemplo del manual), sin embargo, puedes ajustar a tus necesidades, sabiendo que el parámetro `a` representa el acumulador (o valor a devolver) y el parámetro `b` es el elemento actual.

Para este caso, se requiere `reduce()` 2 veces, el primero para separar todas las palabras en un único arreglo y, el segundo, para obtener la palabra más larga.

```js
function laPalabraMasLarga(arreglo) {
    return arreglo
        // Recorrer para obtener todas las palabras en un solo arreglo
        .reduce((a, b) => {
            a.push(
                // Obtener elementos resultantes de split (desesctructurados)
                ...b
                 // Eliminar caracteres no deseados, modifica a tu gusto y necesidades
                .replace(/[,.:\?\+\-\_]/gi, '')
                 // Separar cada palabra por espacios
                .split(" ")
            );
            // Devolver arreglo actualizado
            return a;
        }, [])
        // Recorrer para encontrar la cadena más larga
        .reduce((a, b) => (b.length > a.length) ? b : a);
}

console.log(laPalabraMasLarga(['hola, un placer', 'beber mucha cerveza', 'Con acentos: murciélago']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esto te funcione:

```
    let palabras = ['hola, un placer', 'beber mucha cerveza'];
    
    function buscar_palabra_mas_larga_en_un_string(string) {
        var arreglo_palabras = string.split(" ");
        var longitud = 0;
        var palabra_mas_larga_del_string = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < arreglo_palabras.length; i++) {
            if (longitud < arreglo_palabras[i].length) {
                longitud = arreglo_palabras[i].length;
                palabra_mas_larga_del_string = arreglo_palabras[i];
            }
        }
        return palabra_mas_larga_del_string;
    }

    var longitud=-1;
    var respuesta="";
    for (let elemento of palabras) {
        var palabra_mas_larga=buscar_palabra_mas_larga_en_un_string(elemento);
        var length=palabra_mas_larga.length;
        if(length>longitud){
            longitud=length;
            respuesta=palabra_mas_larga;
        }
    }
    console.log(respuesta);
```

Muestra lo que pides.
Mirando los comentarios, vi que deseas excluir los strings que no son letras, entonces esto puede ser que te sea útil:

```
    let palabras = ['hola, un placer ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,', 'beber mucha cerveza'];
    
    function buscar_palabra_mas_larga_en_un_string(string) {
        var arreglo_palabras = string.split(" ");
        var longitud = 0;
        var palabra_mas_larga_del_string = null;
        const expresion = new RegExp('^[A-Z]+$', 'i');
        for (var i = 0; i < arreglo_palabras.length; i++) {
            if (longitud < arreglo_palabras[i].length && expresion.test(arreglo_palabras[i])) {
                longitud = arreglo_palabras[i].length;
                palabra_mas_larga_del_string = arreglo_palabras[i];
            }
        }
        return palabra_mas_larga_del_string;
    }

    var longitud=-1;
    var respuesta="";
    for (let elemento of palabras) {
        var palabra_mas_larga=buscar_palabra_mas_larga_en_un_string(elemento);
        var length=palabra_mas_larga.length;
        if(length>longitud){
            longitud=length;
            respuesta=palabra_mas_larga;
        }
    }
    console.log(respuesta);
```

Así, en lugar de mostrar ",,,,,,,,,,,,,," muestra "cerveza".

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo el siguiente código que permite hacer un split teniendo en cuenta más de un delimitador; así evitamos que la palabra en el texto ¿llueve? con 6 letras pueda resultar como la mayor en lugar de cerveza con siete letras. El código es como sigue:

```
function GetMaximunLengthWord(str)
{
    // En el split intervienen los siguientes separadores: 
    // ' ', ',' ,'¡', '¿', '!', '?', '.', ';', ':'
    var words = str.split(/[ ,¡¿!?.;:]/);
    var maxLengthWordIndex=0;
    for(var i=1; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        if (words[i].length > words[maxLengthWordIndex].length)
            maxLengthWordIndex = i;
    }

    return words[maxLengthWordIndex];
}


let sentences = ['hola, un placer', 
                 'beber mucha cerveza',
                 'pero, ¿llueve?'];

var maxWordLength="";
for(var i=0; i < sentences.length; i++)
{
    print(sentences[i]);
    // Obtenemos la palabra más grande dentro de la frase
    var auxMaxWordLength = GetMaximunLengthWord(sentences[i]);
    // Vamos comparando a ver si es mayor que la que ya teníamos calculada
    if (auxMaxWordLength.length > maxWordLength.length)
       maxWordLength = auxMaxWordLength;
}

print("\nLa palabra más larga es: " + maxWordLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomando como [referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258375/latin-charcters-included-in-javascript-regex)

```
[
    "hola,que gusto estar aqui hablando contigo",
    "hoy comí puré"
]
    .join(" ")
    .match(/[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff]+/g)
    .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0]
```

Solo tendrás que tener precaución cuando match sea null