# Recorrer un array y en cada posición del array recorrer un array (de strings) para buscar la palabra mas larga. js

Tags: javascript

La funcion llamada 'palabraMasLarga' recibe un array 'array' de frases (strings) como parametro y debe devolver la palabra mas larga entre todas las frases ( Es decir la palabra con mayor cantidad de caracteres). Por ej:

```
palabraMasLarga(['hola esto string', 'frase con palabra']) // debe devolver 'palabra'
```

Lo que quiero hacer es ir recorriendo el array y al mismo tiempo recorrer el cada string o frase. Pero tengo que eliminar espacios en blanco. ¿Qué está fallando?

Mi codigo hasta ahora:

```
function palabraMasLarga(array) {
array.forEach(function(string){ //recorrer el array
    var miarray = string.split(' '); //separar las palabras de cada array eliminando espacios
    var longest = 0;
    var Word = null;
    for (var i = 0; i <= miarray.length; i++) { //bucle
      if (longest < miarray[i].length) {
        longest = miarray[i].length;
        Word = miarray[i];
      }
    }
    return Word;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lo probaste? tira algun error? cual es el problema que tenes?

Comment: ¿Buscas la palabra más larga o la frase más larga?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Encontrar la palabra más larga de un Array con Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369748/encontrar-la-palabra-m%c3%a1s-larga-de-un-array-con-javascript). Cuando se va a hacer preguntas en un foro es bueno buscar antes si alguien ya formuló una pregunta similar antes. Cabe esperar que otros hayan tenido alguna vez dificultades similares.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo devolver la palabra más larga de entre varias frases (strings) pertenecientes a un array ? JAVASCRIPT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384410/c%c3%b3mo-devolver-la-palabra-m%c3%a1s-larga-de-entre-varias-frases-strings-pertenecien)

Answer (score 0):

Hay otras respuestas más óptimas a tu pregunta, igual que hay otras preguntas similares o iguales a la tuya como: [Encontrar la palabra más larga de un Array con Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/369762/165037), pero respetando tu código, acá tienes algunas modificaciones para que funcione como deseas:

```
    <script>
    function palabraMasLarga(array) {
        var Word = "";
        array.forEach(function (string) { //recorrer el array
            var miarray = string.split(' '); //separar las palabras de cada array eliminando espacios
            for (var i = 0; i < miarray
                .length; i++) {
                if (Word.length < miarray[i].length) {
                    Word = miarray[i];
                }
            }
        });
        return Word;
    }
    console.log(palabraMasLarga(['hola esto string', 'frase con palabra']));
</script>
```

Comment: que significa asignarle a una variable esto? var Word = ""

Comment: Eso significa, que la variable Word será inicializada en una cadena vacía (cuyo length es igual a 0).

Comment: Si quisieras que devolviera null cuando el arreglo que se pasa al método está vacío, pero que devolviera una cadena vacía si todos los elementos que se pasan al arreglo son cadenas vacías; entonces debes inicializar en null (`var Word=null`) y antes de comenzar el for que recorre miarray, asignar: `Word=""`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está haciendo tu función es retornar la palabra mas larga pero de el primer elemento
de el array que le pasas ya que estas haciendo el return dentro del `forEach`, si lo que pretendes es retornar la palabra mas larga de **todos** los elementos de el array que le pasas debes poner por fuera del `forEach` las variables `longest`  y  `Word` y despues de terminar el `forEach` hacer el `return Word`.

Ejemplo.

```
  function palabraMasLarga(array) {
    var longest = 0;
    var Word = null;
    array.forEach(function(string){ //recorrer el array
       var miarray = string.split(' '); //separar las palabras de cada array eliminando espacios           
       for (var i = 0; i <= miarray.length; i++) { //bucle
         if (longest < miarray[i].length) {
            longest = miarray[i].length;
            Word = miarray[i];
         }
       }      
    }
    return Word;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

eliminas los espacios en blanco de cada frase:

```js
let arrayFrases = [ "  Hola mundo", "juan pablo perez  ", "a  dfa s df"];
console.log(arrayFrases);

//reemplazas los espacios en blanco
let arrayFresesSinEspacios = arrayFrases.map(x => x.replace(/\s/g, ''));
console.log(arrayFresesSinEspacios);

//ordenas de mayor a menor
let arrayOrdenado = arrayFresesSinEspacios.sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length);  
console.log(arrayOrdenado);
```

Con esto solo tendrías que retornar el item de la primera posición del array ordenado.

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es la frase más larga, puedes hacerlo con `reduce` así:

```js
let arr = ['hola esto string', 'frase con palabra','otrapalabralarga'];

function FraseMasLarga(arr) {
let frase = arr.reduce((crnt, val) => crnt.length > val.length ? crnt: val, '');
console.log('Frase más larga: '+frase);
}

FraseMasLarga(arr);
```

Si lo que buscas es la palabra más larga, puedes hacerlo usando `join` para convertir todo a una cadena y luego `split` para guardar cada palabra en un ***array*** así:

```js
let arr = ['hola esto string', 'frase con palabra','otrapalabralarga'];

function palabraMasLarga(arr) {
    let palabra = arr.reduce((crnt, val) => crnt.length > val.length ? crnt : val, '');
    console.log('Palabra más larga: '+palabra);
    }

palabraMasLarga(arr.join(' ').split(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es otra opción:

```
function palabraMasLarga(palabras) {
  let laMasLargaAux = "";

  const arrayTodasJuntas = palabras.join(" ").split(" ");
  for (const palabra of arrayTodasJuntas) {
    if (palabra.length > laMasLargaAux.length) laMasLargaAux = palabra;
  }
  return laMasLargaAux;
}
```

Ejemplos de uso de la función:

```
palabraMasLarga(["hola esto string", "frase con palabra"]);
```

Devuelve "palabra"

```
palabraMasLarga(["hola estoooooo string", "frase con palabra"]);
```

Devuelve "estoooooo"

---

Explicación del código:

//Creo función que recibirá como parametro array de frases.

```
function palabraMasLarga(palabras) {
```

//Utilizo variable auxiliar, iré depositando la palabra más larga y usando su length para comparar

```
let laMasLargaAux = "";
```

// Creo array con todas las palabras, join devuelve un string con todas separadas por " ", el split pone cada palabra en una posición del array final.

```
const arrayTodasJuntas = palabras.join(" ").split(" ");
```

//Recorro cada palabra en el array generado anteriormente.

```
for (const palabra of arrayTodasJuntas) {
```

//Verifico si el length de la palabra que estoy recorriendo es mayor que el length de la última agregada en laMasLargaAux, si lo es pongo la palabra recorrida.

```
if (palabra.length > laMasLargaAux.length) laMasLargaAux = palabra;
}
```

//Finalmente la función retorna la palabra con el length más alto.

```
return laMasLargaAux;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mi esto sería lo mas exacto, sin embargo puede ser un poco difícil de entender si se esta recién comenzando en javascript.

```js
const palabraMasLarga = function(array){
  return array.join(" ").split(" ").reduce(
    (longest, palabra)=>palabra.length>longest.length ? palabra : longest, array[0].split("")[0]
  )
}
console.log(palabraMasLarga(['hola esto string', 'frase con palabra']))
```

Ojo que el reduce se le hace al array despues de hacerle un join(), esto para unirlo todo en una sola frase y no tener que hacer un loop doble, luego, a este se le hace un split(" ") para obtener todas las palabras separadas, ya que estas se separan por espacios.

Familiarizarse con los métodos de los Arrays que puedes encontrar en la [documentación del prototipo de Array en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) es algo bueno, son bastante utiles.

Lo que hace reduce es básicamente simplificarnos un loop con un acumulador y entregarnos cada valor que se recorre del array, esto es algo que se puede hacer con un for, pero estos métodos hacen la función de ahorrarte ese tipo de cosas.

Lo que se hace en el reduce es ir por cada palabra y guardarla solo si es mas grande que la palabra anteriormente guardada en el '*accumulator*'. En este case use el operador ternario que funciona de esta manera:

```
(condicion) ? valor que se asigna si se cumple : valor que se asigna si no se cumple
(palabraActual.length > palabraAnterior.length) ? palabraActual : palabraAnterior
```

Aqui encontrarás [más información sobre el reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)