# ¿Cuál es error?

Tags: javascript, string, bucle-for

La función llamada 'stringMasLarga', recibe como argumento un arreglo de strings llamado 'strings' y debe devolver el string más largo que hay en el arreglo (Es decir el de mayor cantidad de caracteres)
Ej:

`stringMasLarga(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag']); debe retornar 'guten tag'`

`stringMasLarga(['JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS']); debe retornar 'JavaScript'`

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```
function stringMasLarga(strings) {
palabra_mas_grande = ""
    palabras = strings.replace(",", " ").split(" "); //replace usado para eliminar "," de las palabras.
    palabras.forEach(function(palabra){
    if (palabra.length > palabra_mas_grande.length){
         palabra_mas_grande = palabra
     };
    });
    return palabra_mas_grande 
  };
console.log(stringMasLarga("Hola", "Soy", "Sergio"))

No sé que está mal, pues cuando lo ejecuto me devuelve "Hola", cuando debería ser "Sergio". Gracias de antemano
```

Comment: Esto ya se preguntó [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369748/encontrar-la-palabra-m%c3%a1s-larga-de-un-array-con-javascript) y tiene muy buenas respuestas.

Comment: Espero te sirva [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/384426/184555)

Comment: El error es que estás enviando varias cadenas separadas por coma, cuando deberías enviar un arreglo de cadenas y trabajar directamente con la variable `strings`, en lugar de separar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en la forma de llamar la función, de acuerdo a lo que expones debes enviar un solo parámetro, un arreglo de varias cadenas:

```
stringMasLarga(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag']);
// ['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag'] <-- es un arreglo
```

Pero tú estás enviando varios parámetros:

```
stringMasLarga("Hola", "Soy", "Sergio");
// "Hola", "Soy", "Sergio" <-- Son solo 3 cadenas separadas por coma
```

Solo encierra esas cadenas entre corchetes y funcionará:

```
stringMasLarga(["Hola", "Soy", "Sergio"]);
// ["Hola", "Soy", "Sergio"] <-- Ahora sí es un arreglo
```

Dentro de la función debes trabajar directamente con la variable `strings` y no tratar de manipularla como si fuera una cadena. Usando la [propuesta de @Marcos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/384426/54039), la función quedaría así:

```js
function stringMasLarga(strings) {
    return strings.reduce((acc, val) => {
        return (acc.length > val.length) ? acc : val;
    }, '');
}

// Esto sí funciona
console.log(stringMasLarga(["Hola", "Soy", "Sergio"]));

// Esto va a generar un error porque estás enviando cadenas y no un arreglo
console.log(stringMasLarga("Hola", "Soy", "Sergio"));
```

Comment: Había dado con la solcuión ya, pero esta está muchisimo mejor, más simplificada. Gracias!